# How can I amend my code related to loops to produce the expected output using java?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

So I want to print out something like this when the 'r' argument is integer 5 (Expected output):

```
0 5
1 4
2 3
3 2
4 1
5 0
```

And this is my code currently:

```
public class RandomWalker {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int r = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        for (int i = 0; i <= r; i++) {
            for (int j = r; j >= 0; j--) {
                System.out.println(i + " " + j);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Instead I got this output:

```
0 5
1 5
2 5
3 5
4 5
5 5
```

I know that I can't add "break;" after the "System.out.println(i + " " + j);" line. What should I amend in my current code to produce the expected output? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need two for-loops. Try this:

```
public class RandomWalker {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int r = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        for (int i = 0; i <= r; i++) {
                System.out.println(i + " " + r-i);
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to use two variables, then you can do something like this instead:

```
public class RandomWalker {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int r = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        int j = r;
        for (int i = 0; i <= r; i++) {
                System.out.println(i + " " + j);
                j--;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The first solution is ok, only ammend this line, to include r:

System.out.println( i + " " + r - i );

Comment: @DEVX75 You're right, thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to merge the 2 loops into one:

```
public class RandomWalker {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int r = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        for (int i = 0, j = r; i <= r; i++, j--) {
            System.out.println(i + " " + j);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a stream:

```
IntStream.rangeClosed(r)
   .mapToObj(n -> n + " " + (r - n))
   .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 0):

My java is rusted, but something like this should work :

```java
public class RandomWalker {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int r = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        String string ="";

        for (int i = 0; i <= r; i++) {
            string = i + " " + (r - i);
            System.out.println(string);
        }
    }
}
```